# Load bootstrap table from external file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I want to load the `table.html` file, which contains a table with bootstrap classes, on the index page. The problem is that it does not get style after loading the table. What is the reason?
If I import bootstrap libraries in the `table.html` file, my problem will be solved, but this solution is not suitable because for each bootstrap library call is loaded, I want to import the desired libraries only once in the index page, and each time my tables load in it.

here is my code:  (you can also see https://github.com/yarandish/Challanges)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        var cache = null;
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/table/bootstrapTable/css/bootstrap-table.min.css">

    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/table/bootstrapTable/js/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="text" id="price">
    <input type="text" id="age">
    <button onclick="cache = $('body'); $('body').load('table.html');">load table</button>
</body>
</html>
```

table.html :

```
<table 
    id="table"
    data-toggle="table"
    data-url="data.json"
    data-buttons-class="outline-secondary"
    data-classes="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered"
    data-toolbar=".toolbar" data-maintain-meta-data="true" tabindex="-1"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-multiple-select-row="true"
    >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="name">name</th>
            <th data-field="price">price</th>
            <th data-field="day">day</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rerun the scripts when you add new contents. Just add following code at the end of table.html:

```html
<script>
  $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable();
</script>
```

Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-table-load-wrj45?file=/table.html:511-576) on codepen.

If you don't want to target all the tables then you can also use:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Due to the widespread use of tables across third-party widgets like calendars and date pickers, we’ve designed our tables to be opt-in. Just add the base class .table to any , then extend with custom styles or our various included modifier classes. [ref](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/)

So you need manually those classes to the HTML markup:

- `table` class to the table element
- `col` class to each td/th elements
- `row` class to each tr elements.

Working demo on [replit](https://replit.com/@Louys-PatricePa/Bootstrap-table-style-For-SO-question-70907018)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. You'll have to add the respective classes to `table` elements to have the style from `bootstrap`.